# Orchard 1.6 Wont allow me to create a FK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard 1.6 I have added 
`public virtual int? BusinessCategory_Id { get; set; }` to my 'CustomerPartRecord' table.
And added

```
public int? BusinessCategory_Id
    {
        get { return Record.BusinessCategory_Id; }
        set { Record.BusinessCategory_Id = value; }
    }
```

to my 'CustomerPart' table. In my Migration file I have then added:

```
public int UpdateFrom26()
    {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey("ProductCategoryRecord_CustomerPartRecord", "CustomerPartRecord", new[] { "BusinessCategory_Id" }, "ProductCategoryRecord", new[] { "Id" });
        return 27;
    }
```

So this should take the 'Id' from 'ProductCategoryRecord' table and storing it as a FK called 'BusinessCategory_Id' in the 'CustomerPartRecord' table.

I have tried this before with other values and it has worked but this time I am getting the error: `Foreign key 'Umacs_ProductCategoryRecord_CustomerPartRecord' references invalid column 'BusinessCategory_Id' in referencing table 'Umacs_UMACS_Bradmount_CustomerPartRecord'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

In the logs file it is telling me

```
    2013-07-24 17:38:49,716 [28] Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationManager - An unexpected error orccured while applying migration on UMACS.Bradmount from version 26
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Foreign key 'Umacs_ProductCategoryRecord_CustomerPartRecord' references invalid column 'BusinessCategory_Id' in referencing table 'Umacs_UMACS_Bradmount_CustomerPartRecord'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Also tried deleting the cache file and restarting the devl. server.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the migration code where you created the BusinessCategory_Id column on the CustomerPartRecord table?

Comment: didnt realise you had to actually create a column for your FK. Thought it would have done it automatically when using 'SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey' but thanks for the answer that fixed the problem

Comment: I'll copy it as an answer then, so that you can grant it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create the column before you can make it a foreign key.